# how to delete the previewed image when onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have an array of images like `{A:[img1,img2], B:[img1]}`.

I want to delete those array values that are any previewed images when clicking the delete button.

Each image has a separate delete button.

This is my code:

```
{"balcony":["1477990880.jpg","1477990923.jpg"],"apartment":["1477990905.jpg"]}

   <?php if(isset($multi_images)) 
                    $newArray = array();
                foreach($multi_images as $key => $value) {
                for($i=0; $i<count($value); $i++) { ?>                    

                <div id="filediv">                                    
                    <img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH."/mb-images/delete_pic.png"; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="multiImagedelete" onclick="">
                    <img src="<?php echo SITE_PATH."/data/users/".$value[$i]; ?>" name="images[]" alt="" class="img-responsive" id="<?php echo $key.$i; ?>">

                    <?php array_push($newArray, $value[$i]);?>

                    {{ Form::label($key, $key, array('class' => 'label_field')) }}
                </div>    
                <?php }} ?>
```

Comment: I find the title as well as the post difficult to understand. Guessing you not to be a "native speaker" (of English), I suggest getting someone well versed in your language and English and review the post together: How do you know an image to be previewed? Can there be more (or less) than exactly one array value to delete `onclick`? Please pay heed to [ASK].

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to remove them from the DOM :

```
$('#filediv img').click(function(){

    $(this).remove();  // remove the image (from the dom)

});
```

Or : if you want to delete it from the DB

```
$('#filediv img').click(function(){

    $.post('url-to-your-controller', DATA, function(){

        alert('The file has been deleted from DB');

    })      

});
```

DATA will be for example the id of your image, that you will have set on your img tag :

```
<img src="..." data-img-id="The-id-dynamicly-set-here" />
```

and retrieve it in jquery :

```
$(this).data('img-id');
```

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: using the DOM preview image deleted, but wants to delete the array values permanently ya